# Why is unity overflowing in facebook page app when I scroll

Tags: html, facebook

How can i solve this overflow at the top when I scroll down? This is an application in a facebook page. This is a google chrome snapshot.

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title><?php echo TITLE ?></title>
        <link href="<?php echo CSS; ?>style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/UnityObject2.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var config = {
                width: 760,
                height: 827,
                params: {enableDebugging: "0"},
            };
            var u = new UnityObject2(config);
            jQuery(function() {

                var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".missing");
                var $brokenScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".broken");
                $missingScreen.hide();
                $brokenScreen.hide();
                u.observeProgress(function(progress) {
                    switch (progress.pluginStatus) {
                        case "broken":
                            $brokenScreen.find("a").click(function(e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                u.installPlugin();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $brokenScreen.show();
                            break;
                        case "missing":
                            $missingScreen.find("a").click(function(e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                u.installPlugin();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $missingScreen.show();
                            break;
                        case "installed":
                            $missingScreen.remove();
                            break;
                        case "first":
                            break;
                    }
                });
                u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "GermsBuster.unity3d");
            });

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
                text-align: center;
            }
            a:link, a:visited {
                color: #000;
            }
            a:active, a:hover {
                color: #666;
            }
            p.header {
                font-size: small;
            }
            p.header span {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            p.footer {
                font-size: x-small;
            }
            div.content {
                margin: auto;
                width: 760px;
            }
            .back{
                z-index:10 !important;
            }
            div.broken,
            div.missing {
                margin: auto;
                position: relative;
                top: 50%;
                width: 193px;
            }
            div.broken a,
            div.missing a {
                height: 63px;
                position: relative;
                top: -31px;
            }
            div.broken img,
            div.missing img {
                border-width: 0px;
            }
            div.broken {
                display: none;
            }
            div#unityPlayer {
                cursor: default;
                height: 827px;
                width: 760px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        <div id="fb-root" class="_56b8"></div>
        <div class="video-ar" style="display:none">
            <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="Products_ar.php">video ar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="video-en" style="display:none">
            <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="Products_en.php">video en</a>
        </div>

        <div class="fb-app-requests-container" style="display:none">request</div>
        <div class="fb-user-info-container" style="display:none">user info</div>

        <p class="header" style="display:none"><span><!--Unity Web Player | --></span><?php echo TITLE ?></p>
        <div class="content" style="z-index:-1000 !important;">
            <div id="unityPlayer" style="display:block; z-index:-1000 !important">
                <div class="missing">
                    <a href="https://unity3d.com/webplayer/" target="_blank" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                        <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="images/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="broken">
                    <a href="https://unity3d.com/webplayer/" target="_blank" title="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install.">
                        <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install." src="images/getunityrestart.png" width="193" height="63" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- LIGHTBOX -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.fancybox').fancybox();
            });
        </script>
        <!-- LIGHTBOX -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried embedding it with the flash `wmode` parameter set to `transparent` or `opaque`?

Comment: but this is not flash, how do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fan page "Canvas URL" is not designed by facbook to handle unity applications, use the app page "Canvas Page" instead. You will not face this issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Add style in HTML tag-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="overflow:hidden">
```

Hope it helps